# Tradition of Boxing Day

Tags: tradition

In Australia we have a public holiday on 26th of December and call it Boxing day. Why is it called Boxing Day?
Boxing day is a tradition held each year the day after Christmas in the Commonwealth.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Are you looking for something beyond what is in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_Day)?
Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find
it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]and, in particular [ask].

Comment: See Wikipedia's [Boxing Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_Day).

Answer (score 1):

Boxing day was used (in the UK) by many landed gentry to give a gift to their staff and/or suppliers as a thank you or payment for the services supplied during the year, this could be money or goods  ie food or materials.

This is an easily searched for topic, but one that I have been interested in as it is also my birthday.

I will let you confirm the information provided...